# How to update Relay store without pushing to server

Tags: relayjs, relay

I have a form in my React/Relay app that I am using to modify some fields. I don't want to send a server update every time a new letter is typed into an input. How can I use Relay to support the application state without always pushing to the server? Having read through most of the Relay docs it seems to me that I have to basically copy the Relay state either to the local state of my form or to some other Flux store, deal with changing it in there, and then commit it into Relay. That seems like a lot of extra work though just to keep a local state.

Comment: You can either set the state in the component or use a local store like redux. As far as I know you cannot update the relay store locally in the manner you are describing. Having been through similar scenarios recently I am happy to be corrected. Personally I think that when it comes to a form it is useful not only to keep local state, but also to use local storage to hold onto the state if the user refreshes the page, or comes back later to finish, however that may not fit your use case here.

Answer (score 1):

Relay current version is a glue between graphQL and React, it only handles the data from server.

---

> ...it seems to me that I have to basically copy the Relay state either
>   to the local state of my form...

I fail to see the problem. The way React works, requires you to store `state` for the whole form or for each input separately anyway.

If you add edit functionality (render form and fetch data to populate inputs for user to change them), all the Relay data is available as `this.props.RelayFragmentName` on form level anyway.

You pass it down to inputs where you assign it to `state` and circle is complete. You could also feed inputs directly from `props` (without assigning data to input `state`) and change form `state` from inputs *via* methods.

Now when user makes the changes and confirms it, you'll just collect all the `state` again to make a mutation.

I see it as a complete circle that is basically unbreakable if all the defaults are set.

---

Relay **has** imperative API to get, add or update cache directly but it's relatively dirty and rarely used (especially for local state). It's used for features like WebSockets where you want to push updates from server to client and update cache manually.

Current Relay is meant to work with server data only. Relay 2 has a local cache but it's not out yet.

---

If we're talking about different things or you could use some code samples, let me know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think we're talking about the same thing, though I'd love to see usage of `RelayFragmentName`, haven't seen that before. I guess I just feel like I want to use the API and change state directly in Relay, this passing everything down as props and letting my component be stateless. I just don't necessarily want every relay state change to result in a network request.

Answer (score 1):

In relay modern you can use `commitLocalUpdate` to do that.

For example

```
onEmailChange = (email) => {
  commitLocalUpdate(environment, (proxy) => {
    const userProxy = proxy.get(this.props.user.__id);
    userProxy.setValue(email, 'email');
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I see the function in the repo, but are there any docs about it?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst No, I couldn't find it in their official docs, and although this will work you should use normal component state unless you want these changes to reflect in another component when input change...