# Relay local state management. How to add and use flag on client side?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

#### The problem:

**I want to have simple boolean flag that will be `true` when modal is opened and `false` when it is closed. And I want to update other components reactively depends on that flag**

I hope there is a way to do it with relay only ([Apollo has a solution for that](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/)). I don't want to connect redux of mobx or something like that (It is just simple boolean flag!).

#### What I already have:

It is possible to use `commitLocalUpdate` in order to modify your state.
Indeed I was able to create and modify my new flag like that:

```js
class ModalComponent extends PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        // Here I either create or update value if it exists
        commitLocalUpdate(environment, (store) => {  
            if (!store.get('isModalOpened')) {
                store.create('isModalOpened', 'Boolean').setValue(true);
            } else {
                store.get('isModalOpened').setValue(true);
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Here I mark flag as false
        commitLocalUpdate(environment, (store) => {
            store.get('isModalOpened').setValue(false);
        });
    }

    render() {
        // This is just react component so you have full picture
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div
                className={ styles.modalContainer }
            >
                dummy modal
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('modal'),
        );
    }
}
```

#### The challenge:

**How to update other components reactively depends on that flag?**
I can't fetch my flag like this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return (
    <QueryRenderer
        environment={ environment }
        query={ graphql`
            query MyComponentQuery {
                isModalOpened
            }`
        } //PROBLEM IS HERE GraphQLParser: Unknown field `isModalOpened` on type `Query`
        render={ ({ error, props: data, retry }) => {

            return (
                <div>
                    {data.isModalOpened}
                <div/>
            );
        } }
    />);
};
```

Because Relay compiler throws me an error: `GraphQLParser: Unknown field 'isModalOpened' on type 'Query'.`

And the last problem:
**How to avoid server request?**
That information is stored on client side so there is no need for request.

I know there a few maybe similar questions like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597968/how-to-update-relay-store-without-pushing-to-server) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723878/how-to-use-relay-in-combination-with-complex-local-state-in-client-side-store). But they doesn't ask most difficult part of **reactive update** and answers are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store just one flag as you said, I recommend you to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead of Relay. You could do next:

1. Add Context to App component:

```
const ModalContext = React.createContext('modal');

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isModalOpened: false
        }
    }

    toggleModal = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpened: value
        })
    };

    getModalContextValue() {
        return {
            isModalOpened: this.state.isModalOpened,
            toggleModal: this.toggleModal
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ModalContext.Provider value={this.getModalContextValue()}>
                //your child components
            </ModalContext.Provider>
        )
    }

}
```

2. Get value from context everywhere you want:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const { isModalOpened } = useContext(ModalContext);

    return (
        <div>
            {isModalOpened}
        </div>
    );
};
```

If you will use this solution you will get rid of using additional libraries such as Relay and server requests.

Comment: I like that solution and most likely I'm going to use it. Though it is not really an answer for the question.